# HTML SELECT - possible to have a delayed onchange?

Tags: html, select, onchange

I have a SELECT box that updates a DIV with AJAX when the value of the SELECT is changed.

This AJAX-routine is quite slow, so I only want to call it when it is absolutely neccessary.

I use the onchange event for this.

In Firefox and Chrome this works fine, when using the keys to scroll through the different options. The onchange event is only fired when leaving the SELECT.

But in Internet Explorer the onchange-event fires every time the arrow keys are pressed. I realize most people prefer this, but because of the slow AJAX-call, it makes my SELECT really slow.

What I need is some kind of delayed update... The onchange should be fired only after a few seconds, while not troubling the update when the user is still using the arrow keys to pick the option.

Any idea's how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout to put a delay in (and clearTimeout to cancel it if the user changes before the timeout expires).

Or, if you are using jquery, try looking at queue's and specifically the delay function.

See a full example here: [Delay ajax request by x seconds and update only the last clicked request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995806/delay-ajax-request-by-x-seconds-and-update-only-the-last-clicked-request)

Using jquery and a different approach to what I suggested - I think queue's could make it more succinct, but not able to test it out right now.